# I need help parsing a file in scala for running a spark job

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-spark

I'm running a Spark Job in Scala and I'm struck with parsing the input file.

The Input file(TAB separated) is something like,

> date=20160701  name=mike   age=26
>
> date=20160402  name=john   age=33

I want to parse it and extract only values and not the keys, such as,

> 20160701   mike   26
>
> 20160402   john   33

How can this be achieved in SCALA?

I'm using,

> SCALA VERSION: 2.11

Comment: What have you tried? As presented now, this is a "gimme the code"  question. Please edit the question to include your code and ask specific questions.  Also, please note this has nothing really to do with Spark, it's entirely about string parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSVParser() and you know the location for key, it will be easy and clean

Answer (score 1):

Test data

```
val data = "date=20160701\tname=mike\tage=26\ndate=20160402 name=john\tage=33\n"
```

One statement to do what you asked

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data.split('\n'))
            .map(_.split('\t') // split into key=value
                  .map(_.split('=')(1))) // split those at "=" and select only the value
```

Display what we got

```
rdd.collect().foreach(r=>println(r.mkString(",")))
// 20160701,mike,26
// 20160402,john,33
```

But don't do this for real code. It's very fragile in the face of data format errors, etc. Use `CSVParser` or something instead as  Narendra Parmar suggests.

Answer (score 1):

val rdd = sc.textFile()
rdd.map(x => x.split("\t")).map(x => x.split("=")(1)).map(x => x.mkstring("\t")).saveAsTextFile("")